# How to imperatively assign a prop to a React component?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props, react-component

How do I imperatively add a prop to a component (without using the component tag?)

When I try this:

```
component.props.onChange = onChange;
```

I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'onChange' of object '#'

Here is some more of my code for context.

FormTemplate.js

```
const getComponent = ( onChange, component, ) => {
  component.props.onChange = onChange; // this line throws the error
  return component;
}

const FormTemplate = ({ fields, onChange, }) => {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {
        fields.map( ({ component, ...rest, }) =>
          ( component && (rest.type === 'component') )
          ?
          getComponent(onChange, component,)
          :
          getTextField(onChange, rest,)
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

AppConfig.js

```
const formFieldConfig = {
  zip: {
    type: 'component',
    label: 'Zip code',
    icon: 'place',
    component: <ZipCodeInput />,
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the error says, you can't mutate the props you get directly.
The only way to update the props of a component is to clone the element and add/update props to the cloned element.

```
const getComponent = ( onChange, component, ) =>
  React.cloneElement(component, { onChange })
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another way you can approach this that will keep your code in the context of components (instead of creating the `getComponent` helper function, which adds some indirection), and will probably be clearer to other developers working with this code in the future:

```
const formFieldConfig = {
  zip: {
    type: 'component',
    label: 'Zip code',
    icon: 'place',
    component: ZipCodeInput, // <-- Don't create an element yet
  }, 
}

const FormTemplate = ({ fields, onChange, }) => {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {
        fields.map(({ component, ...rest, }) => {
          const Component = (component && (rest.type === 'component'))
            ? component
            : textField // <-- Assuming this is also a React component

          return <Component onChange={onChange} {...rest} />
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's hard to know for sure that this will work with TextField without seeing the code, but it shouldn't be hard to get it working with `getTextField` as well.